# Formatting IP with sed

Tags: bash, sed, ip

I am trying to figure out how to do the following with sed:

I got a list of IPv4 addresses and I am trying to make them all uniform in the display. So for example: `1.2.4.32` would be `001.002.004.032`. `10.125.62.1` would be `010.125.062.001`.

I am trying to use sed to do it because that's what I am learning right now.

I got these two, which will take any one or two digit number and append zeros at the front.

```
sed 's/\<[0-9][0-9]\>/0&/g' file
sed 's/\<[0-9]\>/00&/g' file
```

But that runs into a more practical problem in that my input file will have single or double digits numbers in other non-IP address places. Example:

```
host-1 1.2.3.32
```

So I need a way for it to look for the full IP address, which I thought could be achieved by this

```
sed 's/\.\<[0-9]\>/00&/g'
```

but not only does that ignore the case of `1.something.something.something`, but also it appends the `00` at the end of 3rd octet for some reason.

```
echo "10.10.88.5" | sed 's/\.\<[0-9]\>/00&/g'
10.10.8800.5
```

---

Sample file:

```
Jumpstart Server jumo     10.20.5.126
Jumpstart Server acob     10.20.5.168
NW1 H17  Node cluster     10.10.161.87
NW1 H17  Node-1       10.10.161.8
NW1 H17  Node-2       10.10.161.9
ts-nw1      10.10.8.6
```

Comment: Does  the contents of the file have pattern? Post an excerpt from the file

Comment: As requested. the file

Comment: thanks, That makes the question more clear :)

Comment: I already have a few sed commands that will sanitize the file a bit, for example all non-IP entries will be concatenated into one string with underscore connecting them, get rid of extra tabs, blank spaces empty lines etc. I know if the input file were all the same pattern then it would be a lot easier but I am aiming for something generic so as to minimize the manual work. I get these files from different people who all do things in their own special way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ cat 37222835.txt
Jumpstart Server jumo     10.20.5.126 10.29.23.24
Jumpstart Server acob     10.20.5.168 dig opt
Jumpstart Server reac     251.218.212.1 rel
NW1 H17  Node cluster     10.10.161.87
NW1 H17  Node-1       10.10.161.8
NW1 H17  Node-2       10.10.161.9
ts-nw1      10.10.8.6
Nw2 HW12 Node-3       192.168.0.1
cluster
```

Doing :

```
sed -n 's/\([1]\?[0-9][0-9]\?\|2[0-4][0-9]\|25[0-5]\)\{1\}\.'\
'\([1]\?[0-9][0-9]\?\|2[0-4][0-9]\|25[0-5]\)\{1\}\.'\
'\([1]\?[0-9][0-9]\?\|2[0-4][0-9]\|25[0-5]\)\{1\}\.'\
'\([1]\?[0-9][0-9]\?\|2[0-4][0-9]\|25[0-5] \)/00\1\.00\2\.00\3\.00\4/g;
s/0\+\([0-9]\{3\}\)/\1/g;p' 37222835.txt
```

gives :

```
Jumpstart Server jumo     010.020.005.126 010.029.023.024
Jumpstart Server acob     010.020.005.168 dig opt
Jumpstart Server reac     251.218.212.001 rel
NW1 H17  Node cluster     010.010.161.087
NW1 H17  Node-1       010.010.161.008
NW1 H17  Node-2       010.010.161.009
ts-nw1      010.010.008.006
Nw2 HW12 Node-3       192.168.000.001
cluster
```

**Advantage over the approach mentioned by @benjamin-w**

This can replace multiple ip addresses in the same line

**Disadvantage(the approach mentioned by @benjamin-w remedy this)**

Had there be a word say `Node-000234` it would be changed to `Node-234`. In fact, you could work on the second substitution command to get the desired behaviour.

Comment: @sjsam Advantage number 2 is now gone ;)

Comment: @BenjaminW. : I knew you would remedy that ;) Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 5):

The idiomatic way of changing only parts of a line is to copy it to the hold space, remove the parts we're not interested in from the pattern space, get the hold space back and then rearrange the pattern space to replace the part we've changed with our new version.

This should work (replace `-r` with `-E` for BSD sed):

```
sed -r 'h                  # Copy pattern space to hold space

# Remove everything except IP address from pattern space
s/.*\b(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})\b.*/\1/

s/([0-9])+/00&/g           # Prepend '00' to each group of digits
s/[0-9]*([0-9]{3})/\1/g    # Only retain last three digits of each group
G                          # Append hold space to pattern space

# Replace old IP with new IP
s/(.*)\n(.*)\b([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b(.*)/\2\1\4/' infile
```

The last step is the most complicated one. Just before it, a line looks like this (newline as `\n`, end of line as `$`):

```
010.020.005.126\nJumpstart Server jumo     10.20.5.126$
```

i.e., our new and improved IP address, a newline, then the complete old line. We now capture the underlined groups:

```
010.020.005.126\nJumpstart Server jumo     10.20.5.126$
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^           ^
      (.*)     \n          (.*)              \b...\b  (.*)
       \1                   \2                  \3     \4
```

and rearrange the line by using group 2, then groups 1 (our new IP) and 4. Notice that

- There are four capture groups, but the third one is just there to help describe an IP address, we don't actually want to retain it, hence `\2\1\4` in the substitution (there are no non-capturing groups in sed).
- The last capturing group (after the IP address) is empty, but having it makes it possible to use this for lines that have the IP address anywhere.
- This only replaces the first IP address on each line, in case there are several.

The overall output is

```
Jumpstart Server jumo     010.020.005.126
Jumpstart Server acob     010.020.005.168
NW1 H17  Node cluster     010.010.161.087
NW1 H17  Node-1       010.010.161.008
NW1 H17  Node-2       010.010.161.009
ts-nw1      010.010.008.006
```

The same as a solidly unreadable one-liner:

```
sed -r 'h;s/.*\b(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})\b.*/\1/;s/([0-9])+/00&/g;s/[0-9]*([0-9]{3})/\1/g;G;s/(.*)\n(.*)\b([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b(.*)/\2\1\4/' infile
```

`\b` is a GNU extension. The script mostly works without it as well; using it makes sure that `blah1.2.3.4blah` is left alone.

Comment: @cyrus oops... On it!

Comment: @cyrus There. `s/[0-9]([0-9]{3})/\1/g` had to be `s/[0-9]*([0-9]{3})/\1/g`. So much for the internal QA on my part! ;)

Comment: `-E` does actually work on GNU sed, just undocumented.

Comment: Nice+1, but this would fail if the ip is not at the end or perhaps there are two ips in a line

Comment: @sjsam Yes, it relies on that. IP addresses at *any* place would be quite difficult to do reliably.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Thanks for the detailed explanation, I noticed that this script would fail if the IP address had extra blank spaces at the end of it but I am not sure why that is happening.

Comment: @D.Zou It relied on the last blank of the line being before the IP address. I've changed it; now it replaces an IP address anywhere on the line. Just the first one of many though, should there be multiple